# Access is Denied, Issue in embedded Derby

Tags: java, database, eclipse, derby

I'm having a problem with my derby engine.

When I make a new database , create new tables and insert or display rows , everything works fine. And when I try to use the database in my practice example , the database works fine and I'm able to insert and select data from the table.

**Code:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;


public class Restaurants
{
    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:c:\\Apache\\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin\\bin\\myDBExample;create=true";
    private static String tableName = "restaurants";
    // jdbc Connection
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        createConnection();
        //insertRestaurants(5, "LaVals Leb", "Berkeley");
        //insertRestaurants(6, "House Leb", "New York");
        selectRestaurants();
        shutdown();
    }

    private static void createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void insertRestaurants(int id, String restName, String cityName)
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();      
            stmt.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values (" +
                    id + ",'" + restName + "','" + cityName +"')");            
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void selectRestaurants()
    {
        try
        {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = results.getMetaData();
            int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i=1; i<=numberCols; i++)
            {
                //print Column Names
                System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+"\t\t");  
            }

            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

            while(results.next())
            {
                int id = results.getInt(1);
                String restName = results.getString(2);
                String cityName = results.getString(3);
                System.out.println(id + "\t\t" + restName + "\t\t" + cityName);
            }
            results.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void shutdown()
    {
        try
        {
            if (stmt != null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
                conn.close();
            }           
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

This code works fine but when I try to create a connection to the same database again with ij , I get an error in my command prompt like this:

[image]

In the image, the upper part is when I first make my database but after that when I use it in eclipse, it gives me this error. Even using a db in eclipse once will result in this error.

What is the issue? Why is derby engine not getting the access granted to it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you confused the database modes here. In your question's title you mention "embedded Derby", but you're code is using the ClientDriver and the *create=true* attribute, which does create the DB if it doesn't exist, but it doesn't start the server.

If you don't want to start the server, you can just use the EmbeddedDriver.

Another point where you might run into problems is with the *shutdown=true* attribute. You're using the entire DB URL (dbURL) including the filename, but if you want to shut down the server from your code, you should omit the filename, like this : *jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true*.

You can check out the [Derby developer docs](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop15.html) for information on using these attributes, and the [Embedded Derby tutorial](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html) for using Derby in embedded mode, sou you won't have to worry about starting the server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: No worries, I've been through pretty much the same confusion, but with Groovy. Forgot to mention that if you use Derby in embedded mode, only one connection at a time will be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. I had to start the derby as a network server on the port by using the following command:

```
startNetworkServer.bat
```